# AngularJS variable not showing in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Structure**

statsController.js

```
(function (module) {
    'use strict';

    var statsController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $routeParams, $location, $window, statsService) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
            $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.url() });
        });

        var model = {};
        model.stats = {};

        statsService.getStats().then(function (d) {
            model.stats = d;
        });
    };

    module.controller("statsController", statsController);

}(angular.module("app")));
```

statsService.js

```
(function (app) {

    var statsService = function (webapi) {

        var model = {};

        model.getStats = function () {
            return webapi.get('stats/getstats');
        }

        return model;
    };

    app.factory("statsService", statsService);
    statsService.$inject = ['webapi'];

}(angular.module("app")))
```

stats.html

```
Total paid customers: {{statsController.model.totalPaidCustomers}}<br/>
Stripe confirmed customers: {{statsController.model.stripeConfirmedCustomers}}<br />
```

Result from API:

```
{"totalPaidCustomers":1,"stripeConfirmedCustomers":2}
```

When I put alert() in **statsController.js** for d.totalPaidCustomers I get value 1, same for other parameter.

So only problem is to show this in html.

App.js

```
.when('/stats', {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/admin/stats.html',
            controller: 'statsController',
            controllerAs: 'stats'
          }).
```

Comment: your `model` isn't on `$scope` in the statsController.

Comment: Are you using ui-router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I didn't assign the current scope to a model.

**var model = this;**

statsController.js

```
(function (module) {
    'use strict';

    var statsController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $routeParams, $location, $window, statsService) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
            $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.url() });
        });

        var model = this;
        model.stats = {};

        statsService.getStats().then(function (d) {
            model.stats = d;
        });
    };

    module.controller("statsController", statsController);

}(angular.module("app")));
```

Then call in html:

```
Total paid customers: {{stats.stats.totalPaidCustomers}}<br/>
Stripe confirmed customers: {{stats.stats.stripeConfirmedCustomers}}<br />
```

have to change name of var though(stats.stats), confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly. It should be "model.stats"

```
Total paid customers: {{statsController.model.totalPaidCustomers}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5hb9spz/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your state definition to this:

```
.when('/stats', {
    templateUrl: 'tpl/admin/stats.html',
    controller: 'statsController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
}).
```

Then change the controller to this:

```
(function (module) {
    'use strict';

    var statsController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $routeParams, $location, $window, statsService) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
            $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.url() });
        });
        var vm = this;
        vm.model = {};
        vm.model.stats = {};

        statsService.getStats().then(function (d) {
            vm.model.stats = d;
        });
    };

    module.controller("statsController", statsController);

}(angular.module("app")));
```

Finally your view goes to this:

```
Total paid customers: {{vm.model.stats.totalPaidCustomers}}<br/>
Stripe confirmed customers: {{vm.model.stats.stripeConfirmedCustomers}}<br />
```

If you don't see anything then just put this in the view and see what you have:

```
{{ vm | json }}
```

Comment: Nothing shows in html, I've updated my question with App.js routing settings. This is from console.log for model.stats  Object { totalPaidCustomers=1,  stripeConfirmedCustomers=2}

Comment: You put ALL of those bindings in and see nothing? I updated the answer to include a few more things.

Comment: I have this in console.log  Object { totalPaidCustomers=1,  stripeConfirmedCustomers=2} for model.stats and this is html inspect: http://puu.sh/ndCHc/cad2ecfb4f.png

Comment: for some reason it doesn't show anything in html. it's breaking my brain

Comment: Can you reproduce in a fiddle or plunker? Do you see any other random errors in your browser's dev tools console log?